# Install whereis command on alpine linux

Tags: command-line, packages, alpine-linux

I'm trying to install the whereis command on alpine linux 3.5

Actually I'm running the following command:

```
apk add --update whereis
```

But it is not working since I get this error:

```
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.5/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.5/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  whereis (missing):
    required by: world[whereis]
```

It seems there is not a package whereis, surely I miss something.
What should I do to get the whereis command?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You need to install the `util-linux` package:

```
apk add --update util-linux
```

Which contains the `whereis` binary.